# Angular - Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: typescript, angular-6

Em um aplicação Angular8 o componente criado não identifica o comando *ngFor, e retornao erro: 
`Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

Código da View ContabilComponent:

```
<p>contabil works!</p>
<div *ngFor='let c of contas'>1</div>
```

Código do ContabilModule:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ContabilComponent } from './contabil/contabil.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ContabilComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class ContabilModule { }
```

Código do ContabilComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContabilService } from './../contabil.service';
import { ContabilDTO } from 'src/app/shared/model/contabil.dto';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contabil',
  templateUrl: './contabil.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contabil.component.scss']
})
export class ContabilComponent implements OnInit {

  private contas: ContabilDTO[] = [];

  constructor(private contabil: ContabilService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.contabil.list('').subscribe(response=>{
      this.contas = response;
      console.log(this.contas)
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
}
```

Código do AppModule

```
import { MenuaccordionModule } from './shared/components/menuaccordion/menuaccordion.module';
import { UsuarioModule } from './modules/usuario/usuario.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserService } from './core/services/user.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './modules/home/home.component';
import { AuthInterceptorProvider } from './core/interceptors/auth.interceptor';
import { ErrorInterceptorProvider } from './core/interceptors/error.interceptor';

import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    UsuarioModule,
    MenuaccordionModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ErrorInterceptorProvider,
    AuthInterceptorProvider,
    UserService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Como fazer com que o ngFor seja reconhecido na view?

Comment: Como assim **que o ngFor seja reconhecido na view**?

Comment: O erro retornado informa que não é possível vincular o ngFor pois é uma propriedade desconhecida pela div (que se encontra na view, arquivo html). Eu não estou conseguindo fazer o ngFor funcionar.

Comment: Não tem o menor sentido esse erro, se declarou o módulo **BrowserModule** no AppModule e o **CommonModule** no componente, não tem o pq do erro!

Comment: Pois é, já verifiquei sintaxe, apaguei e recriei módulo e componente, e sempre o mesmo erro. Continuo na busca. Em outros pontos da aplicação o ngFor esta funcionando corretamente, então não se trata de algum problema na instalação do angular.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro da classe ContabilComponent o atributo contas esta como privado, o que impede que ele seja renderizado na View. O atributo foi modificado para public, corrigindo assim a falha.

```
 public contas: ContabilDTO[] = [];
```